# Hibernate: One to Many not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, hibernate

Something strange is going on with hbm.xml implementation here.
**Parent Mapping**

```
<list name="children" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all">
    <key>
        <column name="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
    </key>
    <list-index column="sequence"/>
    <one-to-many class="Child"/>
</list>
```

**Child Mapping**

```
<many-to-one name="parent" class="Parent"  cascade="all">
    <column name="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
```

**Exception**

```
"not-null property references a null or transient value: Child.parent"
```

**Child Class**

```
public class Child {
  private Parent parent;

  //parent getter and setter
}
```

> Using Hibernate 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this exception when you pass `Child` object to `session.save()` and this `Child` object has `parent = null`.

Very common and recommended pattern is to use such convenience method in Parent class:

**Parent.java**:

```
public void addChild(Child c) {
    if (children == null) {
        children = new ArrayList();
    }

    children.add( c );
    c.setParent( this );
}

// make setter private
private void setChildren(List<Child> children) {
    this.children = children;
}
```

Private setter setChildren will be used internally by Hibernate.

Method addChild should be used by you when you build/modify your Parent object.

Comment: `addChild(Child c)` will be used by hibernate? or do I need to call it from some setter?

Comment: I just edited answer to make it more clear - addChild is for you to append child to children collection in convenient way. Setter may be private to make sure that only hibernate will use it.

Comment: `setChildren()` is being used by other classes so I can not change it to `private`. But I did change setChildren() to set `Parent` for each `Child`.

Comment: Did the exception disapear when you set parent on child object?